# Property 'post' does not exist on type 'HttpClient' Angular 7

Tags: angular7

I am having the following error in an Angular 7 app:

```
Property 'post' does not exist on type 'HttpClient'
```

The code that I am using is in the following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Car } from '../models/car';
import cars from '../cars/car-list';
import { HttpClient } from 'selenium-webdriver/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CarService {

  private cars: Car[];

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { 
    this.cars = cars;
  }


  addCar(car: Car): Observable<any> {
    this.cars.push(car);
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/cars', car);
  }
```

Can you help me sort out this error?!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you imported `HttpClientModule` in your `app.module.ts` ?

Comment: Yes, I have had already imported HttpClientModule in my app.module.ts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
import { HttpClient } from 'selenium-webdriver/http';
```

to:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

And also import **HttpClientModule** in components parent module